# OO and mysqli in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli

I've defined my connection file like this

file name = `connection.php`

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$database = "projectp_peas";
$usr= "projectp_admin";
$pass = "9613341694";
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $usr, $pass) or die (mysqli_error($conn));
?>
```

My connection is ok. ()

Now My First Class:
filename `product.php`

```
<?php
class Product{

public $PRODUCT;
public $SHORT_DESC;
public $LONG_DESC;

public function showProduct($id){
include_once("conection.php");

mysqli_select_db($conn, $database);
$products = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE ID = '$id' ";
$rs_products = mysqli_query($conn, $products) or die (mysqli_error($conn));
$product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_products);

echo "<h3 style=\"font-size:3em; color:#BBBBBB;\"> ";
echo $product['PRODUCT'] ."</h3>"; 
echo "<h5> ";
echo $product['SHORT_DESC'] ."</h5>"; 

echo $product['LONG_DESC']; 
}

}
?>
```

Now My  `index.php` file

```
<div class ="px_70">
<?php
 require_once('../script/product.php');
 $product = new Product;
 $product->showProduct(1);
?>
</div>
```

My Query is running fine till now.

But my problem starts with another class. The other class is like this:

Filename : `clients.php`

```
<?php
class User{
public function TopMenu(){
include_once("conection.php");
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['EMAIL'])){
$MAIL = $_SESSION['EMAIL'];

mysqli_select_db($conn, $database);
$username= "SELECT * FROM CLIENTS WHERE EMAIL = '$MAIL' ";
$USERNAME_RS = mysqli_query($conn, $username) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$USR = mysqli_fetch_assoc($USERNAME_RS);

if(mysqli_num_rows($USERNAME_RS)>0){
echo $USR['C_NAME'] . " | <a href=\"../global/logout.php\">Log out </a> | <a href=\"UserPapers.php\"> Papers &nbsp; &nbsp;</a>" ;
}

else{
echo " <a href=\"../login.php\">Login</a> | <a href=\"../Register.php\">Register &nbsp; &nbsp;</a>" ;
}
}

else{
echo " <a href=\"../login.php\">Login</a> | <a href=\"../Register.php\">Register &nbsp; &nbsp;</a>" ;
}
}
}
?>
```

Again in `index.php` file:

```
<div class="tm">
<?php
include_once('../script/clients.php');
$top = new User;
$top->TopMenu();
?>
</div>
```

Why am I getting the following errors?

```
Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/projectp/public_html/script/product.php on line 11

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/projectp/public_html/script/product.php on line 13

Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/projectp/public_html/script/product.php on line 13
```

the function TopMenu() in the file should not cause any error. because this function works fine, when I remove the `Product` class.
Can anyone tell me, where am I making error ? I am very new to php OO and mysqli.

Comment: It would be a good idea to remove the password! Or to never post a password in the first place.

Comment: `include_**once**`...

Comment: Don't move your DB creation/connectivity inside of a completely unrelated class/method. If you need to create abstraction for your DB layer then create a DB class. It's similar to buying a mobile phone. You wouldn't buy several so you can have a mobile phone in every single room of your house. You'd buy one and take it around with you.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't define `$conn` in your function. That's all.

You could define `$conn` as a property of your class.

```
class Product {
    private $connection;
    public function __construct($connection) {
        $this->connection = $connection;
    } 
    public function showProduct($id) {
        $database = ... ;
        mysqli_select_db($this->connection, $database);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change `include_once` to `include` here:

```
class Product{

public $PRODUCT;
public $SHORT_DESC;
public $LONG_DESC;

public function showProduct($id){
include("conection.php");
```

and here:

```
class User{
public function TopMenu(){
include("conection.php");
```

Comment: This gives me `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Db...` I've googled and found that `require_once` is the solution. but in my case `require_once` gives me the same previous error..

Comment: in your case - you can't use `require_once`, or `include_once` the way you develop you must use `include`, or if you want to redesign your application, I will set another answer, just let me know if you still need a solution

Comment: Yes I need the solution. I've read many forums, tried various ways, but still no fruit.

Comment: so what error message do you have when do my changes with `include`?

Comment: there is no `class DB` in `conection.php` you published, and there is no `class DB` in code I offered. so this message is not related to my answer. Show the full contest of your `conection.php` or follow just one answer: mine or anybody else but just one at the same time.